# How to add padding to a ul/li menu with a background image?

Tags: html, css

I have the following menu:

CSS:

```
            ul.menu {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            ul.menu > li {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            ul.menu > li:hover {
                color: red;
            }

            ul.menu > li a {
                display: block;
                background:transparent url("http://placehold.it/25x25") right center no-repeat;
                background-size: 15px 15px;
            }

            ul.menu > li > a:hover {
                background-color: #F7F7F7;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 200px; background-color: lightgrey;">
    <ul class="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Line 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Line 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Line 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Line 4</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TzMc/

So far so good, but I want there to be padding on the left and right sides of the li's (about 10px) and I would also like the height of the li's to be a little greater (so that there's some space between the lines of text). I tried adding this line to the `ul.menu > li` CSS, but it messes up the menu in two ways:

1. There is now a non-clickable gap between the tops and bottoms of the menu items
2. The background image is messed up

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HXrgq/

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Could you add padding to the `anchor`? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8TzMc/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `padding` to the `a` element instead of the `li` element.

```
ul.menu > li a { padding:10px;}
```

for example

Updated [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8TzMc/2/)

Comment: Thanks, it almost works, but it doesn't look like the padding is being added to the background image on the right?

Comment: The `padding` won't affect the `background-position`, you need to change that to something like `background:url("http://placehold.it/25x25") 170px center no-repeat;` where `170px` is the `background-position` from the `left`

Answer (score 1):

Add padding to  `ul.menu > li a`  instead, it gets rid of the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/HXrgq/1/

On the li element, do:

```
text-indent: 10px;
line-height: 1.5em;
```

seems this is what you searched: text indented (I suppose this is only one line?) and `line-height`.